# Remove text from CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, text

I'm using Wordpress and I want to remove author info from a box in the footer. 
This is the HTML code of the box:

```
<footer class="entry-footer clearfix">
: :before
<span class="entry-cats">
<span class="entry-label">
<i class="fa fa-tag">
: :before
</i>
Categorie:
</span>
<a href="http://ec2-52-57-169-182.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/categoria-quale-scegliere/">Quale scegliere</a>
</span>
<!--End .entry-tags-->
<span class="entry-separator">
: :before
/
</span>
<a class="entry-comments" href="#">Nessuna risposta</a>
<span class="entry-separator">/</span>
di
<a class="entry-author" href="http://ec2-52-57-169-182.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/author/user/">Admin</a>
: :after
</footer>
```

This is the image of 
[Footer box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa5rq.png)

I just removed author name directly in CSS with:

```
.entry-author{
display:none !important;
}
```

Now I need to remove the slash between "Nessuna risposta" and also the word "di" (in English "by").
I don't know how to do because this is text and not a class.
Firefox Inspector show the text as #text

If you want to watch it directly on the website, go [here](http://ec2-52-57-169-182.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/differenze-bearing-principali/) and later go down on the page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the slash it's `a.entry-comments + span.entry-separator: { display: none; }`

For the word "di"  it would be best to wrap it in a span and assign that a class, which you can hide with `display: none;`.